# Nested object, how to avoid manual conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Usually I do something like this:

```
// Form values
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    field1: "",
    field2: ""
});

// Field description
const FIELD_DESCR = {
    field1: "First field description",
    field2: "Second field description"
};
```

then in next page I do something like this to show data that user inserted in form:

```
{Object.keys(values).map((fieldKey => (
    // If the filed has a value
    values[fieldKey] != "" ? (
        <li>{FIELD_DESCR[fieldKey]}: {values[fieldKey]}</li>
    ) : null
)))}
```

the problem is that now I have a values object that can be very nested, for example something like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    field1: "",
    obj1: {
        field2: ""
    },
    obj2: {
        field3: "",
        obj3: {
            field4: "",
            obj4: {
                field5: ""
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I do to what I did in the first case without doing it manually like this:

```
{values.field1 != "" ? (
    <li>First field description: {values.field1}</li>
) : null}
{values.obj1.field2 != "" ? (
    <li>Second field description: {values.obj1.field2}</li>
) : null}
{values.obj2.field3 != "" ? (
    <li>Third field description: {values.obj2.field3}</li>
) : null}
{values.obj2.obj3.field4 != "" ? (
    <li>Four field description: {values.obj2.field3}</li>
) : null}
{/* etc etc */}
```

Additional info: I'm using React Hook Form, so I do something like this in inputs:

```
{ ...register("field1") }
{ ...register("obj1.field2") }
{ ...register("obj2.field3") }
{ ...register("obj2.obj3.field4") }
```